# Bind parameters Vs Inline Values for Estimation Plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, database-performance

I would like to know using Bind Parameters on SQL Query for constructing Execution Plan.

In many scenarios the developer write a dynamic SQL query and place the appropriate values in the Query.

While reading this, http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/bind-parameters I feel using Bind Parameters will improve the performance because of using same execution plan.

Here is an example with Bind Parameter in dynamic query constructed in SP.

```
CREATE Procedure GetEmployee 
AS
(
@eName NVARCHAR(100),
@eDept NVARCHAR(50)
)

BEGIN
Declare @sql NVarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @params NVARCHAR(MAX)

 SELECT @params = N'@name nvarchar(100), ' +  
                    N'@dept nvarchar(50) ' 

SET @sql='Select EmpId, Name from Employee where Name=@name AND Department=@dept'

sp_executesql @sql, @params, @eName, @eDept

END
```

**How this really improve performance Vs WHERE Name='''+@eName+'''?**

Comment: The binding is not done by the database, but rather on the server application side.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk, Fine. Binding will used for caching execution plan or will it vary?

Comment: Binding has nothing to do with the execution plan as far as I know.

Comment: I read those from http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/bind-parameters. Not sure why they written like that :(

Comment: That article specifically talks about binding on the API side.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk, see the Tip section at that post 'Not using bind parameters is like recompiling a program every time.'

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk, So writing dynamic query in SQL has no impact on execution plan? Can i replace all my 
params to inline values into in sql statment as i have mentioned?

Comment: I don't see how a dynamic SQL statement affects the execution plan... All you are doing is writing the statement to be executed dynamically, ***then*** executing it.

Answer (score 2):

As the article suggests, the SQL Server query optimizer *can* use cached execution plans for sp_execute_sql.  The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is quite explicit.  And the advantage over just `execute` is that the query will more likely match something in the plan.

A note about the plan itself.  The query plan is generated the first time the query is run with parameters.  This is what is placed in the cache.  For a simple query such as yours, the query plan should be fine for subsequent calls.  Even in this case, though, you could have the situation where you start with 10 rows in the table and an index, and the query plan decides to scan the table.  When you add another 100,000 rows, it still wants to do a scan (until you reboot the server or empty the cache some other way) because that is the cached plan.

In other cases, though, the values of the parameters can affect the query plan.  So, recompiling the query each time may not be a bad idea.  If the query is going to run for any length of time (seconds), then the compilation overhead is likely to be minor.

Comment: Pretty well. Compilation time seems like always very less when we query 10 million records. I am querying 10 million records now. So i think i should concentrate how better i can query, rather than worrying on this estimation plan :)

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of bind variables is, that the RDBMS

1. doesn't need parse/compile the statement and
2. doesn't need to evaluate an excution plan again and again.

Usually a certain number of statments and execution plans are cached so some time is saved here. However: if you fill up this cache with thousends of similar statments, it won't help so much anymore.

So finally the core execution of the statement itself won't be quicker - only the things around (parsing, compiling, creating execution plan).

Answer (score 1):

How this really improve performance Vs WHERE Name='''+@eName+'''?

Simply building on what others have stated. What goes into the plan cache for the sp_executesql is going to be a plan that is applicable to anyone calling that method. It will have a placeholder for the variable(s) and apply them at runtime. It won't need to compile a new plan so you can save the cost.

Additionally, and this can be a big difference, is that with the former, there will be **1** plan generated for *all* the variable combinations passed in. With the latter, you are going to get 1 query plan for *each* variable combination. It *may* logically be the same Index Seek, Sort, etc operators applied but instead of the placeholders in the plan, there will be one plan for eName = 'Bob', one for eName = 'William', etc.

The downsides to having those unique plans is that takes away available memory for other plans to be cached. Plan's not in the cache? Gotta compile and oops, plan cache is full, time to pick the least recently used plan and kick it out. Next query comes in, it needed the plan we just binned and the plan cache swapping cycle goes on.

One last thing to note with regard to at least the .NET side of things. In the linked example, this line of code `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subsidiary_id", subsidiary_id);` is fine because it is dealing with an integer. Ints are ints are ints. But, if you were going to inline your query above, the parameters `@eName` and `@eDepartment` can result in different query plans because the `AddWithValue` method is going to do some guessing and it may not come up with a consistent definition for your variables. It may decide one is nvarchar(30) and the next is nvarchar(29) and now you have two plans. By using a stored procedure, you alleviate that concern as the parameters define the sizing and there's not guessing involved.